# Get WebView object from Fragment to Activity

Tags: java, android

In my `Action Bar` there is a button where you can add a favorite, but to do that I need to have my `mWebView` object that I can't seem to get from `FavoriteFragment` despite using the same code like in my `MainActivity` to get in the `LoadUrlFragment` it crashes as soon the onclick triggers.

How can i get that `mWebView` in my activtiy without crashing it?

MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_favoriten:
        if (fragmentName.equals("LoadUrlFragment")) {
            WebView mWebView = ((LoadUrlFragment) fragment).getMWebView();
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.saveFavoriteData('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
        } else if(fragmentName.equals("FavoritenFragment")) {
            WebView mWebView = ((LoadUrlFragment) fragment).getMWebView();
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.saveFavoriteData('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Favoriten können hier nicht gesetzt werden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

LoadUrlFragment

```
public WebView getMWebView() {
    return mWebView;
}
```

FavoriteFragment

```
public WebView getMWebView() {
    WebView mWebView = ((LoadUrlFragment) fragment).getMWebView();

    return mWebView;
}
```

FavoriteFragment where I loade my LoadUrlFragment

```
fragment = new LoadUrlFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("url", allFavorite.get(position).getUrl());
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

LogCat

```
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340): Process: ch.digvis.abcproduction, PID: 11340
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340): java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.digvis.abcproduction.fragment.FavoritenFragment cannot be cast to ch.digvis.abcproduction.fragment.LoadUrlFragment
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at ch.digvis.abcproduction.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:188)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1019)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:546)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:119)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4569)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18553)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
12-05 14:57:07.588: E/AndroidRuntime(11340):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: your `onOptionsItemSelected` is in the `Activity` right?

Comment: yes it's a default function that I override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change

```
else if(fragmentName.equals("FavoritenFragment")) {
        WebView mWebView = ((LoadUrlFragment) fragment).getMWebView();
```

to

```
else if(fragmentName.equals("FavoritenFragment")) {
        WebView mWebView = ((FavoritenFragment) fragment).getMWebView();
```

This looks like a nice copy & paste based exception :)

Comment: Thanks so much, for some reason i just couldn't see it and i tried so many stuff to try to fix it.